# Why does it show Nan when i run this?

Tags: java, math, quadratic

This code is to solve a quadric equation in Java. It output puts `Nan`.
What is the wrong and how can I resolve this?

I tried `a=1, b=2, c=10`.

```
import java.util.*;

class equation {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a, b, c;
    String input;
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a value for a: ");
    a = key.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Enter a value for b: ");
    b = key.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Enter a value for c: ");
    c = key.nextInt();


    //finding roots
    double temp = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c);

    double root1 = (-b + temp) / (2 * a);
    double root2 = (b + temp) / (2 * a);

    System.out.println("Answers are " + root1 + " or " + root2 + " .");
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJdFh.jpg)

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: integer values@Yassin Hajaj

Comment: Please tell us specifically what values you are trying this with

Comment: The equation is `-b` +/- the square root. i.e. `(b + temp)` should be `(-b - temp)`

Comment: I tried a=1, b=2, c=10 @Sam

Comment: @Nimantha those inputs don't have a real solution and since `double` doesn't support imaginary numbers it reports `NaN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check possible domain conditions for your code to work.

From your question i am sure that you had given input where `b*b-4*a*c<0` thats why it returned NAN

Here is complete code

```
    Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in):
    double first = z.nextInt();
    double second = z.nextInt();
    double third = z.nextInt();
    double d = (second * second - 4 * first * third);
    double re = -second / (2 * first);
     if (d >= 0) {  // i.e. "if roots are real"
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(d) / (2 * first) + re);
        System.out.println(-Math.sqrt(d) / (2 * first) + re);
    } else {
      System.out.println(re + " + " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2 * first)) + "i");
      System.out.println(re + " - " + (Math.sqrt(-d) / (2 * first)) + "i");
    }
```

Comment: Here i made negative value in squareroot to positive to get desired output

Answer (score 3):

You get this result because you don't use `Math#sqrt` correctly.

`b * b - 4 * a * c` must be positive.

---

### **From the `Math#sqrt` Javadoc**

> ◦If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.

---

### Addition (from @PeterLawrey)

So if you input `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=10` then `b * b - 4 * a * c` is `4 - 40` or `-36` and the square root is `6i` which is an imaginary number which double doesn't support so `Math#sqrt` returns `NaN`.

Comment: So if you input `a=1, b=2, c=10` then `b * b - 4 * a * c` is `4 - 40` or `-36` and the square root is `6i` which is an imaginary number which `double` doesn't support so Math.sqrt returns NaN. + 1

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes that's exactly the behaviour of `Math#sqrt`

Comment: I mentioned this example as this is what the OP is inputting ;)

Answer (score 0):

For `a=1, b=2, c=10:
 Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)`means `Math.sqrt(-38)` The behaviour of   Math.sqrt() is it retuns `NAN` if the parameter is negative( which is in your case).